# Finding a vector function for the curve of intersection of two surfaces

Tags: calculus, surfaces, parametric

I wanted to find a vector function $\mathbb{r}(t)$ for the curve of intersection between $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z = y+5$.  I understand that one way would be to let $x=t$ and then we can set $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = y + 5$ to get a function $y = f(x)$.  Is letting $x=t$ my only choice of parameterization?  Is letting $y = t$ valid?  What about $z = t$?  Why or why not?  My concern with letting $y =t$ is that when we equate the two surfaces, solving for $x$ does not yield a function of $y$ since a square root is involved.

Comment: I’m not sure what exactly it is that you’re asking here. Since you can’t express $x$ as a function of $y$, $y$ is probably not the best choice for a parameter for this curve. On the other hand, if the intersection were with the plane $z=x+5$, the story would be different.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I guess my general question is this: how do know how to make the choice of parameter?  Also when you say $y$ is probably not the best choice, does that mean it is incorrect to choose $y$?  If a correct function can be made by choosing $y$, what does it look like?